# Unable to load Utility File

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am trying to load a utility file called as apiclient which is present in

app/stores/util

My distribution folder has a file cfile.js which is calling this file using the following code :

```
var api = require('../util/apiclient');
```

I am able to load the component files etc which are present in the app/components folder via a similar code and they work without any issue. But when i try to load the API client i just keep getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../util/apiclient'
```

This is how my files and directories are present http://prntscr.com/7qkovs

Could someone help me out over here ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `cfile` your transpiled/bundled version of your app? Or something else? If it's bundled, then you most likely have an issue in your actual source, which is just carried over to the bundled file.

Answer (score 0):

Well your structure is like this:

```
clinical-notes
  app
    stores
      util
        apiclient.js
  dist
    cfile.js
```

So when going from `cfile.js` to `apiclient.js` the correct require path would be `../app/stores/util/apiclient.js`.

But this is neither a reactjs nor flux problem ;)

Comment: No i already tried that but its still showing the same error
      Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../app/stores/util/apiclient'

Comment: Is your `cfile.js` the result of a bundle operation? If so, your error is most likely in your source files and is just carried over.